# Set multiple Parameter Schemas for TBB?

Tags: web8.5, templating

Suppose I have 2 custom TBBs, each with their own Parameter Schema. During development, I noticed that there are parameters that are shared between the two.

Is there a way to assign multiple Parameter Schema per TBB? So that I can extract the shared parameter properties into a base Parameter Schema. Are there any guidelines for defining parameters used across multiple TBBs?

My current solution is to push any shared parameter value(s) from the 1st TBB to the Package to be reused by the 2nd TBB but not sure if this approach is ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign multiple parameter schemas to a single TBB.

Not really sure if there is an ideal solution for your case, ideal implying that there are no downsides. That said, you could use an "alternative" approach (I say "alternative" because it's somewhat similar to yours). This approach would be a combination of a Component which holds your parameter values and a TBB which reads said Component and pushes all the values in the Package. The improvement in comparison with your current approach is that the reading/pushing of the parameter values is delegated to a separate TBB, it's not cluttering your first one. The downside being that now you have centralized your parameters to a single point, losing the capability to use the same TBB but with different parameters.

Improving on this approach, you could have a Parameter which tells the TBB (which reads the component and pushes values) which Component to read (via WebDAV). That way you could have different parameters per Template level.

Comment: Thank you. I'll review my parameters and consider their scope. It might be that I need to consolidate them into a single component to be then extracted and pushed to the package by a new TBB as you be suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you can achieve what you want by simply using an Embedded Schema. If you put the shared fields into an Embedded Schema and then add that as a field to each Parameters Schema, they will both have the shared fields.